# Triple core: a black sheep?

Tags: multi-core, core

Is there any architectural disadvantage in a triple core processor compared to a dual or quad core? For example, does a triple core imply some architectural dissymetry that impacts performance?

P.S. Part of the context of my question is I'm considering buying a machine based around the Phenom X3 which seems suspiciously good value.

Comment: Rephrased properly (to be about programming on 3 cores), this might get some interesting answers at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, it's true that there are potentially some implications from a programming point of view (there are some divide-and-conquer algorithms that tend to make two-way splits). As a programmer myself, I was interested in hearing the arguments from the point of view of the hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first (cynical) thought was that these may be simply 4-core processors with a faulty core.

And sure enough, at the Hot Hardware link provided by [idigas](https://superuser.com/users/2127/ldigas), the first comment says the same thing and *the image of the die strongly suggests 4 cores*.

Of course, they could have used that image because it was handy.

We can't underestimate the attraction to AMD (and others) of selling a processor which is mostly functional.

Comment: I remember when HDD's were that way ... different capacities according to what made it out of manufacturing process ... 118Mb disc was actually 124Mb.

Comment: Yes, with a list of bad sectors to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but they were somehow factory marked. You didn't see them in normal usage (at home/work ...). What I mean you couldn't access them easily ... 'twas a long time ago, I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 1):

Programmers are taught to do try and write code that is multithreaded in multiples of two, since servers had two to four physical CPUs. Over time, they progressed to duals and quads, etc. Everything up to now has been in multiples of two.

There isn't necessarily a performance penalty for a triple core, it's just that a lot of current code is optimized to use cores that are a multiple of two. A triple core's performance should be no worse than a dual core of the same spec if the code is properly written. Overall system performance will be better as there are additional cores to handlw background tasks.

Comment: We aren't simply "taught" to work with multiples of two; it's a natural product of a system based on electrical signals with only two states: on and off, 1 and 0, binary.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at there. You can certainly represent odd numbers in binary, and 99% of code being written is abstracted from the 1's and 0's of the circuitry that it runs on. I'm talking about threads being spawned in multiples of two, APIs being optimized for processing by CPUs with even numbered cores. Compilers that compile code that is more friendly for an even number of cores, etc.

Comment: the statement "Programmers are taught to do try and write code that is multithreaded in multiples of two" is inaccurate, to say the least. Other words come to mind, too.Multithreading as programming principle is not subject to multiples of something. You start as many threads as required and/or useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is a matter of following some guidelines, and history ... them being rare ... but they do exist: [AMD Triple Core Phenoms Announded](http://hothardware.com/News/AMD_TripleCore_Phenoms_Announced/)

Personally, I prefer even to odd numbers ... don't know why, just do. Symmetry is beautiful :)

Comment: Binary pairs 'n' all, eh? :)

Comment: @techie007 - yup

Comment: aren't those triple core CPUs 'failures'? a core failed QC and was disabled or something? the 4th core seems to be present anyway: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/amd-phenom-cpu,7080.html

Comment: @Molly - Some dual cores are failed quads. Some single cores were failed duals. It doesn't mean the quality is poor, it's common practice.

Comment: yep, this practice going back a long time, back to the venerable 486SX, which was in fact a DX with a faulty (disabled) FPU :)

Comment: There is no DX like a 386DX :) (my gawd, I had that machine for almost 15 years).

Comment: but the 386 SX/DX was different, the former only had a 16/24/32-bit bus, while the latter had a full 32-bit bus :)

Comment: yep. also, if you stuck a mathematical coprocessor on it (on DX) you could run everything that had a minimum requirement up to pentium100 ...

Comment: If it wasn't for 'failed' CPUs marked at lower clock rates, there'd be way fewer overclocking fanatics.  My Pentium 166 ran at 266 for years. :)

Comment: You know why they named the Pentium processor "Pentium" ? Because 486+100 = 585.9545 :)